# Render animation to WebM with 'Transparent' alpha channels?

Tags: rendering

I saw this question asked, but all of the answers were out of date by a couple years.  Since most web browsers now support Webm with alpha channels, has Blender included a way to encode alpha channels to Webm?

If not, could someone provide an ffmpeg cli command to render a png sequence to a webm with alpha channels?  I don't see anything in the ffmpeg manual.

Comment: Seems there is no option in 2.93.4... `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -f image2 -i frames/%03d.png -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm` from [Convert PNGs to webm video with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34974258)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to succeed by doing all of the following 5 things.  Missing any 1 of these 5 things will cause your animation to render without an alpha channel.

1. Under *Properties Window > Render Properties > Film* check *Transparent*
2. Under *Properties Window > Output Properties > Output* change *File Format* to *FFMPEG Video*
3. Under *Properties Window > Output Properties > Encoding > Container* choose *WebM* (Webm can hold transparent alpha, other containers might work, but tis one is certain)
4. Under *Properties Window > Output Properties > Encoding > Video > Video Codec*; set to *WEBM/VP9* (again, other might work, but I know this combination works)
5. Under *Properties Window > Output Properties > Color* set to *RGBA*.

Now your animation will have transparent alpha.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Blender ``3.2``

Comment: @Monstar Of course this works correctly with version **3.2**. I have just tested it. If it doesn't work for you, the application where you are processing the material obviously can't handle transparency, or your implementation is buggy.