# Why is exporting webm with transparency not working?

Tags: rendering, file-format, encoding

I have a scene in blender `3.2.1` with

- *Properties Window* > *Render Properties* > *Film* > *Transparent* checked
- *Properties Window* > *Output Properties* > *Output* > *File Format* set to *FFMPEG Video*
- *Properties Window* > *Output Properties* > *Encoding* > *Container* set to *WebM*
- *Properties Window* > *Output Properties* > *Encoding* > *Video* > *Video Codec* set to *WEBM/VP9*
- *Properties Window* > *Output Properties* > *Color* set to *RGBA*.

Just like in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/239389/132496).

And yet transparency doesn't work; when I drag the video to a browser (firefox/chrome) the background isn't transparent.

**I tried**:

- Rendering as transparent PNGs first (transparency works on those) then render as webm again.
- Using blender `2.9` instead of `3.2` but the render crashed

**Update**:
Using a third party, [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/), gave me a working transparent `.webm`, so the issue seems to come from within the blend file.

[image]

Comment: Switch the Conteiner from Webm to Matroska, that worked for me in past uses... The best recommendation is to render an image sequence and then use the video editor to render the image sequences to video, but is just optional

Comment: @Emir That gave me an ``.mkv`` which I can't use, I need the ``.webm`` file format

Comment: @Monstar I just tested this with this answer here and it works fine: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/239389/145249 Either the processing application can't use transparencies, or you're doing something else wrong here. Do you plan to use this in *HTML5*?

Comment: @quellenform As mentioned in my question I have done everything like in that answer, yet it still doesn't work, and as I see in your reply there it does work in Blender 3.2, so my guess is it could be a bug in the blend file somewhere?

Comment: @quellenform I drag & drop the ``.webm`` into my browser and edit the ``<html>`` ``background`` property to see if there is transparency.  
I got it to work by exporting from an other software (see answer update) but not by exporting from Blender, which means the way I test for transparency works and isn't the issue

Comment: @Monstar Try this: `<html lang="en"><head></head><body style="background-color:red;"><video width="600" height="100%" autoplay loop muted playsinline><source src="VIDEOFILE.webm" type="video/webm" /></video></body></html>`. If that doesn't work, then your video actually has no transparency, or the browser doesn't support video with transparencies.

Comment: @quellenform That works, but what's very surprising is that it actually works even with a drag & drop into the browser now, I don't understand what's different from yesterday...